# Update (find and replace) in all column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this script for update data in table:

```
update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]
set [PRA] = replace([PRA], '.', ',');
update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]
set [PRV] = replace([PRV], '.', ',');
update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]
set [TVK] = replace([TVK], '.', ',');
update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]
set [eAl] = replace([eAl], '.', ',');
update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]
set [efH] = replace([efH], '.', ',');
```

But there is 53 columns in the table and listing script for each column separately is inefficient. Is there a possibility to perform this script comprehensively for the whole table?

Like:

```
update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]
set * = NULL
where * like '***'
```

Comment: All the three update statements are same

Comment: Why to set `null` and not delete the row?

Comment: @dns_nx - Setting a column with `NULL` doesn't mean that he don't want the entire row

Comment: @Prdp but OP said, for all column? lets wait OP

Comment: Do you mean update `[dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]
set col1 = case col1 like '***' then NULL else col1 end, col2 = case col2 like '***' then NULL else col2 end, ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

To generate a script like that use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @tableName varchar(50) = '[dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy]'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';

-- columns
SELECT @sql = @sql 
   + CASE len(@sql) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE ',' END 
   + c.name + ' = CASE WHEN ' + c.name +  ' LIKE ''***'' THEN NULL ELSE '  + c.name + ' END'
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)

SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + ' SET ' +@sql ;

select @sql;

EXECUTE (@sql);
```

Comment: Nice one! I just want to suggest to add filtering of columns, I assume OP don't want to change data in all columns. :)

Comment: Good point. Another possible check is datatypes of columns `INNER JOIN sys.types y ON c.system_type_id = y.system_type_id
  AND y.name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = (
SELECT 'update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy] set [' +COLUMN_NAME+'] = replace(['+COLUMN_NAME+'], ''.'', '','');'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'temp_LABORATOR_copy'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('Field2','Field3') -- Here put columns that must not be updated
AND DATA_TYPE IN ('nvarchar','varchar','nchar','char')
FOR XML PATH('')
)
--That will give you script like
--update [dbo].[temp_LABORATOR_copy] set [Field1] = replace([Field1], '.', ','); and etc

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```